# How to process data with slightly different formats?

Tags: excel, preprocessor, etl

I would like to automate the processing of some data in .xls files. The data format varies as it come from different sources.

The manual processing of the data outputs a file with this format:

ID(a number)|NAME(a string)|PRICE(a float)

As I said the information is in general in columns but it can be in rows or there can be two tables in which I have to process only one.

I considered three approaches:

1. Using the Strategy pattern. Cons: I will have to code each case anyway.
2. Using an ETL tool. Cons: I think it is more than I need.
3. Using a linear regression or neural network or other machine learning algorithm in which the examples would be a pair of (.xls raw file, .xls processed file) . Cons: I don't know what the metric for the objective function would be (a similarity between two excel files?)

Thanks for any help or hint!

Comment: Bit too non-specific a question for here perhaps: it seems clear from your question that you're not an inexperienced programmer, but I'm guessing without a lot more detail about the variety of possible input formats (3? 300?) it would be hard to suggest a "best" strategy.

Comment: The number of different formats is around 70, anyway most of them are pretty similar which is why I think using the Strategy pattern -or simply a class with methods for processing each format- would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Using a linear regression or neural network .

This is one of the difficult situations,as the data format varies.
What i have observed in my project is , we code each and every time using an ETL tool(ssis).
Using a linear regression or neural network  is difficult and need good skill and understanding of the modeling.